# ¿Cómo obtener la fecha actual (dd, MM,HH, mm) en diferentes variables en java?

Tags: java, date, datetime, date-format

Necesito obtener por separado cada componente de la fecha actual, ya que necesito por ejemplo concatenar a un String el día a dos digitos, en otro String concatenar solo el mes, en otro String las horas y en otro String los minutos por ejemplo

tengo este formato , pero no se como obtener los componentes de toda la fecha actual en diferentes variables

```html
Date todayDate = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
String fechaActual = sdf.format(todayDate);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No se que versión de java usas, pero a partir de java 8 en adelante puedes usar el API `LocalDateTime`.
Ejemplo:

```
        LocalDateTime hoy = LocalDateTime.now();  
        
        System.out.println("El día es: "+hoy.getDayOfMonth());
        System.out.println("El mes es: "+hoy.getMonthValue());
        System.out.println("El año es: "+hoy.getYear());
        System.out.println("Minutos: "+hoy.getMinute());
```

Comment: si en el mes me regresa 7, y quiero que sea a 2 digitos o sea 07 como se podria?

Comment: @Root93 Si está entre 1 y 7 añades un 0 a ese número con el .concat, sino está entre 1 y 7 que devuelva el mes normal

Comment: @Root93 puedes hacer ``if(hoy.getMonthValue()<10)`` concatenar ``"0"+String.valueOf(hoy.getMonthValue());``

Comment: y si por ejemplo la variable mes me regresa 7, y requiero llenar la variable mes con 5 caracteres, que los demas sean ceros, es decir "00007", pero si mi variable mes me regresa "11" y debo llenarlo a 5 caracteres, es decir "00011", como se puede hacer?

Comment: @Root93 es la misma idea, ``if(hoy.getMonthValue()<10)`` concatenas ``"0000"+String.valueOf(hoy.getMonthValue())`` else concatenas ``"000"+String.valueOf(hoy.getMonthValue())``

Answer (score 2):

También lo puedes hacer usando el método SimpleDateFormat que tienes en tu código

```
//declaramos una variable tipo fecha donde almacenamos la fecha
Date todayDate = new Date();

//Usando el método SimpleDateFormat, recuperamos solo el día
SimpleDateFormat dia = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
//Usando el método SimpleDateFormat, recuperamos solo el mes
SimpleDateFormat mes = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
//Usando el método SimpleDateFormat, recuperamos solo el año
SimpleDateFormat ano = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");

//almacenamos el día en la variable string fDía
String fDia = dia.format(todayDate);
//almacenamos el mes en la variable string fMes
String fMes = mes.format(todayDate);
//almacenamos el año en la variable string fAno
String fAno = ano.format(todayDate);

//imprimimos el día    
System.out.println(fDia);
//imprimimos el mes    
System.out.println(fMes); 
//imprimimos el año  
System.out.println(fAno);
```